# Can a file be dragged from Google Drive to the Gmail compose window?

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-docs, gmail-attachments, document-management

I'd like to find a super-easy way to get a Google Doc or sheet into an outgoing Gmail message, in the browser. I'm imagining that if I set up two windows, one with the Gmail compose window and one with the open spreadsheet or else the hierarchical file structure (Drive) visible, there must be some way to drag and drop. I've tried dragging this and that and haven't hit on anything that works, though.

If the answer is no, it's not possible, then I'd be open to suggestions of an *efficient* way of getting a google doc into an email.

Note: the file in question is already in a folder that is shared with the recipient (in case that makes a difference).

Comment: why not use proper way?

Comment: Why not just try it?

Answer (score 2):

There is an icon for that purpose:

[image]

Which will open this window where you can select your file (for example from Recent tab) or narrow down the view to find your file. You can also choose how you want to insert it on bottom right:

[image]

If you are looking for something more fancier you can try this extension:

- **[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSAuQ3Xxago)**
- **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/send-to-for-google-drive/nblkgijaoagipfalahhdfdiahflpdgom)**